# Marvel TV Series chronology question

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, x-men-cinematic-universe, suggested-order

I recently discovered that there is some new TV series around the X-men Universe (MARVEL):

The gifted, Iron Fist, The defenders and Legion. There is only 1 season for each of them for now.

I know that "The defenders" show unite, Luke Cage, Daredevil and Jessica Jones each having their own TV show.

**What series should I watch first to "respect" the chronology? *(if they're related in a way)***

Comment: There are way more series, BTW. Check https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/45654/31029 for a viewing order of the "full" universe.

Comment: Iron Fist and Defenders are not "X-men Universe", they are Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, *Legion* and *The Gifted* are separate shows and so are not (currently) affected by the others. Nor are they likely to as they cover a different *mythology* (X-Men / Mutants) than the Netflix series.

As for the order for the rest it would be be:

- Daredevil season 1
- Jessica Jones season 1
- Daredevil season 2
- Luke Cage season 1
- Iron Fist season 1
- The Defenders
- The Punisher
- Jessica Jones season 2

This is not only the chronological order for the releases but also the Netflix/MCU timeline (excluding flashbacks and some overlaps).

---

Regarding the other series, Wikipedia says

> *Legion* is an American cable television series created for FX by Noah Hawley, based on the Marvel Comics character David Haller / Legion. It is connected to the X-Men film series.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(TV_series)

and

> *The Gifted* is an American television series created for Fox by Matt Nix, based on Marvel Comics' X-Men properties. It is connected to the X-Men film series, set in an **alternate timeline** where the X-Men have disappeared.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gifted_(TV_series)

---

Other TV Shows include *Agent Carter* (2 seasons), *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, cuurrently in season 5 and *Inhumans*, only 1 season so far (and unlikely to get another).

Those shows air(ed) on the ABC network (also owned by Disney) and have no overlap with each other (except by implication) or the other shows listed.

Comment: There are other TV shows too, Agents of SHIELD, Inhumans etc

Comment: Yes, but the OP didn't ask about those

Comment: Yea i'ma aware of those, Agent Carter also and more .. Thanks anyway

Comment: It's sad that Agent carter got the boot. I liked very much the Marvel One shot approach

Comment: All X-men related stuff is currently within in there own universes, and I say universes because there are several confirmations from EPs that many of the none MAIN X-Men films are in their own universes/realities and do not directly connect to the main films. Legion, Deadpool, The Gifted, and potentially New Mutants are all thought to be in their own universes. I can make an answer with quotes, if one would like.

Comment: @DarthLocke I think it's covered..but you can add an additional answer if you want.

Answer (score 4):

Although your question was not not limtited to or only specificed to **The X-Men Franchise**, I thought I would add some clarity to the X-Men portian.

The main franchise which consists of two (possibly 3 timelines, depending on what is exactly true about ***Logan***'s placement) are directly connected to themselves.

**Main Films:** X-Men, X2, X-Men: The Last Stand, X-Men Origins: Wolverine, X-Men: First Class, The Wolverin, X-Men:Days of Future Past, X-Men: Apocalypse, Logan, X-Men: Dark Pheonix (upcoming)

However, the X-Men spin offs: ***Deadpool***, ***Legion***, and ***The Gifted*** are often characterized being in their **own separate universes from each other** and the main X-Men films -- and DO NOT DIRECTLY Connect.

### Legion

> Landgraf stated, in January 2016, **that the series would be set in a
>   universe parallel to the X-Men films where "the US government is in
>   the early days of being aware that something called mutants exist but
>   the public is not"**.
>
> The producers hoped that audiences would watch the show because of its
>   character-focus and the talents of Hawley and the cast, rather than to
>   "see a Marvel franchise show."[57]Donner also noted that **having Hawley
>   focus on Haller's perspective of reality rather than connections to
>   the X-Men films allowed the series to avoid the convoluted continuity
>   of the films,** "because we play with so many different timelines, and
>   we rebooted and not really rebooted and all that" throughout the
>   films. Therefore, "the cinematic universe will not worry about Legion.
>   They will not worry about these TV worlds at all. 
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_(TV_series)
>
> “It’s not in the continuity of those films in the sense that the
>   current X-Men films take place in a  universe where everybody on
>   planet earth is aware of the existence of mutants. **Legion takes place
>   in a parallel universe if you will where the government is aware
>   mutants exist but the public is not.** I wouldn’t see characters moving
>   back and forth because they really are parallel universes**.”
>   http://www.slashfilm.com/x-men-tv-series-legion/

---

### The Gifted

> The Gifted is an American television series created for Fox by Matt
>   Nix, based on Marvel Comics' X-Men properties. It is connected to the
>   X-Men film series, **set in an alternate timelinewhere the X-Men have
>   disappeared.** The show is produced by 20th Century Fox Television in
>   association with Marvel Television, with Nix serving as showrunner.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gifted_(TV_series)

---

### Deadpool

> "**What's nice is Deadpool exists in his own universe. He's part of the
>   larger X-Men universe, but in a way he isn't.** He interacts with that
>   world but he is in the present. We don't deal with the '60s or the
>   '70s or the future. It's here and now. More than anything, I think
>   he's going to have his fun with what they do in the other franchise.
>   But fortunately, we don't have to play by those same rules. Deadpool
>   is a movie that did break all the rules.
>   http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/01/26/deadpool-writers-explain-how-the-movie-fits-into-the-x-men-timel/

---

Although there has yet to be any public statement about if **New Mutants** will also follow suit and be in it's own universe, it seems likely given how they have treated other spin-offs and knowing that, at least before *Dinsey's* possible merger (it is not yet finalized), it was said to be a "trilogy"

> ...in May 2015, Fox finalized a deal to have Boone direct The New
>   Mutants, from a script by himself and Lee, with Kinberg and Lauren
>   Shuler Donner producing. **The film would be a standalone spinoff film,
>   expanding the universe of the X-Men films.**[9] While working on the
>   first draft of the script, Boone sent it and his ideas for the film to
>   Sienkiewicz, who thought Boone "had it figured out" but was also not
>   just copying the comics.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_Mutants_(film)

However, there is potential in some of these cases to see "alternate" versions of main X-Men film characters. In earlier development, Professor X was said to be in *New Mutants*, but James McAvoy has officially shot down rumors of appearing in the film. Noah Hawley, however has stated that he would like get Professor X for *Legion*, since it is important part of the main character's story in the comics. Season one also heavily referenced Xavier. Hawley says he thinks it's a matter of time, but this was also before the beginnings of Disney's merger...